# When the boundary of any subset is compact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space with no isolated points such that the boundary of any subset of $X$ is compact. Does it mean that $X$ is compact ? (If $X$ is a resolvable space then it is clearly compact.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your property implies in particular:

"Every nowhere dense closed subset of $X$ is compact."

(A nowhere dense closed subset is the boundary of its complement.)

This in turn is equivalent to compactness for $T_1$ spaces with no isolated points, as shown by Katetov in 1947. Interestingly, the result holds as well for Lindelöf spaces, or more generally for $[\lambda,\kappa]$-compact spaces (a space is $[\lambda,\kappa]$-compact if every cover of it by $\le\kappa$ open sets has a subcover of cardinality $<\lambda$). This is due to Mills and Wattel, a very nice short proof can be found in Blair's "Some nowhere densely generated topological properties" (easily found online).

Completely unaware of these results, I actually recently published a paper whose main result is weaker than Mills and Wattel's, and with a more complicated proof than Blair's.

Comment: Can you give the full citations of the papers you mention here?

Comment: You can find all the references in Blair's paper, which can be found here, for instance: https://eudml.org/doc/17268?lang=cs&limit=10

Comment: +1 Thank you. Any informatin for general Tychonoff spaces? I mean not necessary spaces without isolated points.

Comment: If $X$ is a $T_1$ space each of whose nowhere dense subsets is compact, then either $X$ is compact, or there is a clopen infinite discrete subset in $X$. Let me sketch the proof (following Blair). Take a cover $C$ of $X$. Take a maximal disjoint family $F$ of open sets such that each one is contained in a member of $C$. Take one point $x_U$ in each $U$ in $F$. Then $X-\cup F$ is closed and nowhere dense, cover it with finitely members of $C$. The $x_U$ not covered form a closed discrete set. (cont.)

Comment: If there are only finitely many of them, take the members of the cover that contain the corresponding $U$s, this gives a finite cover of $X$. If there are infinitely many, either there is a infinite subset such that $\{x_U\}$ is open, so there is a clopen discrete subset, or infinitely many points are non-isolated, so they form an infinite discrete closed nowhere dense set, which is thus not compact.